# Can't post form, customized with ajax

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I made a Django form with some selects, which depends on each other (user selects option in first select(grade) and get some values in second select(subject) depending on its value):

```
class AddTaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    grade = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Grade.objects.all())
    subject = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.none())
    topic = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    ...
```

I'm getting subject values by ajax-request and dynamically changing select with subject like this (sorry for intends in next block, i'm new to JS and don't know how do it properly) :

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
                    $('select[name=subject]').append('<option value="' +
                                                      key + '">' + value +'</option>');
                    });
```

But when I click "submit" button, I'm getting this message, belonging to select, that I dynamically changed:

`Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

I've checked for html-code and it's exactly the same, that should be in standard form.
What I'm doing wrong and how I can dynamically get values in second form?

Comment: So you're loading the choices, but are any of the choices being selected? All your js is doing is rendering the choices list, not actually selecting one of the choices.

Comment: @CurtisOlson yes, of course, message appears even I select some option on page, I attached only part of code, that appends new options, because the rest of code isn't important in question (as I think)

Comment: Okay, well what is `key` returning in your js - I assume each key is a pk of your returned `Subject` instances?

Comment: @CurtisOlson yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

You will have to send all subject values from the server and then ajax request can narrow down the options for you.

Comment: It's close to right answer - selected option in changed dropdown must be in `queryset`, I'm just now solved my problem :)